# How to move something to either left or right in python?

Tags: python, loops

Having a problem, lets say I have this code (easiest possible):

```
n=5
j=3
for i in range(n):
    print("kurt")
for x in range(j):
    print("karl")
```

If I want this to be printed like a protocol, that is, I don't want them after each other, I want my second for-loop to be to the right of the first for-loop when I print it, like this:

```
kurt karl
kurt karl
kurt karl
kurt
kurt
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your desired output?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help, I got one more question, is it possible to let a for loop print horisontal instead of vertical?

Comment: @A.Maine it'll be easier to answer your follow-up question if you post a new top-level question, since it's not possible to post code examples in comments here. Also, please consider accepting one of the answers to this question, if it answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just put them in one print statement.

Here I've told it to loop for the maximum number (in this case `5`) and then if the loop has reached the minimum number (`3`) to stop printing the second one.

```
n = 5
j = 3
for i in range (max(n,j)):
    if i < min(n,j):
        print("kurt" + " " + "karl")
    else:
        print("kurt")
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to print the values of next loop in right of previous loop, you can achieve it by writing this:

In python 2.7

```
for i, k in zip(range(n), range(j)):
   print "kurt",
   print "karl"
```

In python 3.x

```
for i, k in zip(range(n), range(j)):
       print("kurt", end=" ")
       print("karl")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
first = ['kurt']*j
second = ['karl']*n
for l,r in  izip_longest(first ,second ):
   print l,r
```

output:

```
kurt karl
kurt karl
kurt karl
None karl
None karl
```

if you want white space.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
first = ['kurt']*j
second = ['karl']*n
spaceJ,spaceN = len(first [0]),len(second [0])
for l,r in  izip_longest(first ,second ):
   print l if l else ' '*spaceJ,
   print r if r else ' '*spaceN
```

output

```
kurt karl
kurt karl
kurt karl
     karl
     karl
```

Comment: rather than 5 and 3, you should use n and j.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this printing of "kurt" and "karl" is just an example of a more complex problem you're trying to solve, a general strategy for this sort of problem is to use Python [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to run the two loops concurrently, and then combine the results for output.

For example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

n = 5
j = 3

def kurt():
    for i in range(n):
        yield "kurt"

def karl():
    for x in range(j):
        yield "karl"

for kurt_result, karl_result in zip_longest(kurt(), karl(), fillvalue=""):
    print(kurt_result, karl_result)
```

When a function body contains the `yield` keyword, Python produces a generator rather than a regular function. A *generator* will, when called, return an iterator that produces a value each time `yield` is called, and then waits until the next value is read before proceeding to the next `yield`. Once the generator function returns, the iteration ends.

The final `for` loop here then uses [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), which is a utility function that takes two or more iterators and produces another iterator that yields the sequence of combinations of reading from all of the given iterators at once, allowing you to easily match up the corresponding results from each iterator.

This code then produces the following output:

```
kurt karl
kurt karl
kurt karl
kurt 
kurt
```

(The above assumes Python 3. If you were using Python 2, the `zip_longest` function was then named [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), so you'd need to adjust the two references.)